# Unable to toggle code folding in Aptana PyDev editor

Tags: aptana, pydev, code-folding

Does anyone know if it is possible to toggle code folding to expand/collapse code under APtana PyDev editor?  I looked around and it seems that all you need to do is go to Preferences -> General -> Key and then Toggle Folding with binding Ctrl+Numpad_Divide when "Editing Text"
and then hit "Ctrl+Numpad Divide" when editing, and then code should expand/collapse......

However, when I do this, nothing happens, but I do want to note that I am able to manually expand and collapse code by clicking on the +,- symbols on the side.....
I'm also working under Aptana Studio 3, build:3.1.2...

Has anyone had any luck with toggling or even have each file automatically collapse when it is first open?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having it collapse when it's first open is a feature that's not implemented -- please feel free to create a feature request -- or ideally, provide a patch if you're up to the task :)

Also, the toggle is not implemented in PyDev, only the collapse/uncollapse (or collapse all/uncollapse all) -- you can see those in the keybindings preferences page (window > preferences > general > keys) and searching for 'collapse' in the 'pydev editor scope'. If you really think toggle is nice to have, please issue a feature request (and a patch would be appreciated too, as I don't think this will get high on my priority list very soon).

Comment: I didn't know there was a collapse all key, that is better than toggle and it works great!  thank you!

Comment: @FabioZadrozny thanks for pointing to the keyboard shortcuts, great answer!